Adobe PDFServicesSDK Execute command does not work
I am trying to convert some non pdf file formats to pdf and I am using the Adobe PDF SDKs.
It doesn't crash, it doesn't throw any error. It simply hangs there.
When I invoke this from Console Application, it does work. I am not sure what is the thing I am missing here. Please let me know.
Thank you
Please find the sample code here :
Dim source As FileRef = FileRef.CreateFromLocalFile(localFilePath)
createPdfOperation.SetInput(source)
Dim outputPDF As FileRef = createPdfOperation.Execute(executionContext)
The execution stops at
"Dim outputPDF As FileRef = createPdfOperation.Execute(executionContext)"
